# Replacing bytes in NSData with hex values

Tags: cocoa

The user enters a value between 0 and 5000 into a text box. My need is to replace bytes 4 and 5 in dataToSend with the hex value in the text box. For example, if the user enters 250 I translate that into 00FA. In dataToSend, replace 0x03 with 0x00 and 0xEB with 0xFA. str and str2 are there so I can see the data. There is a difference between them, and I don't know which is correct.

```
- (IBAction)handleConfig1DelayMoveChange:(id)sender
  {
    NSString *tmp;
    int value;
    tmp = [txtDelayBeforeMove1 stringValue];
    NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%04lX",(unsigned long)[tmp integerValue]];
    NSString *hex1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04lX",(unsigned long)[tmp integerValue]];
   dataToSend = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&((char[6]){0x51,0x04,0x02,0x03,0xEB,0x0D}) length:6];
   NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataToSend encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*s", [dataToSend length], [dataToSend bytes]];
   tmp = @"";
   tmp = [hex1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,2)];
   value = [tmp intValue];
   [dataToSend replaceBytesInRange: NSMakeRange(3,1) withBytes: &value];
   str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*s", [dataToSend length], [dataToSend bytes]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Comments and suggestions for improvement are welcome. displayhexStr was used to verify changes while debugging.

```
- (IBAction)handleConfig1DelayMoveChange:(id)sender
  {
    NSString *tmp;
    int i;
    if([txtDelayBeforeMove1 intValue] < 0 || [txtDelayBeforeMove1 intValue] > 5000)
    {
      [self showAlert:@"Value must be between 0 and 5000"];
      return;
    }
    tmp = [txtDelayBeforeMove1 stringValue];
    NSString *hex1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04lX",(unsigned long)[tmp integerValue]];
    dataToSend = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&((char[6]){0x51,0x04,0x02,0x03,0xEB,0x0D}) length:6];
    NSMutableString *displayhexStr =
    [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[dataToSend length]*2];
    for (i = 0; i < [dataToSend length]; i++) {
      [displayhexStr appendFormat:@"%02x ", dbytes[i]];
    }
    tmp = [hex1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
    NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tmp];
    unsigned int intValue;
    [scanner scanHexInt:&intValue];
    unsigned char uc = (unsigned char) intValue;
    [dataToSend replaceBytesInRange: NSMakeRange(3,1) withBytes: &uc];
    displayhexStr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[dataToSend length]*2];
    for (i = 0; i < [dataToSend length]; i++)
    {
      [displayhexStr appendFormat:@"%02X ", dbytes[i]];
    }
    tmp = [hex1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,2)];
    scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tmp];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&intValue];
    uc = (unsigned char) intValue;
    [dataToSend replaceBytesInRange: NSMakeRange(4,1) withBytes: &uc];
    displayhexStr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[dataToSend length]*2];
    for (i = 0; i < [dataToSend length]; i++)
    {
      [displayhexStr appendFormat:@"%02X ", dbytes[i]];
    }
    [self send];
}
```